# Need to create dynamic tiles using twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using angular to return a set of objects. I'd like each object represented in the dom by a div, something like

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div ng-repeat="x in loaders" class="col-sm-2">
    <div style="padding:15px;width:350px;">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="font-size:60pt;">{{x.id}}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="padding-left:30px;font-weight:bold;width:100%;">
                        <div>{{x.loaderCustomHeader}}</div>
                        <div>Type:&nbsp;{{x.loaderType}}</div>
                        <div>Last Run Time:&nbsp;{{x.lastRunTimeFormatted}}</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

I'd like these divs to simply render onscreen and when the width of the container div is reached to move to the next line until it's full. Is this the ideal way do this with boostrap or should I be using some other classes for this effect? I kind of have what I want but the margins are off.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? More details for "I kind of have what I want but the margins are off". One thing that's apparently wrong is that the `col-sm-2` should be wrapped in a `row`.

Comment: Sorry. All I want to do is have each object in the collection render inside the table html above, and have them render side-by-side until the width of the div is reached, then move to the next row unti all the objects have been rendered.

Comment: Yeah, that's how Bootstrap works: http://bootply.com/EEt2y92xgP

Comment: Okay the bootstrap seems to be working. I was having issues with the "tiles" overlapping. My only question is, why is it giving me 3 tiles across when i use col-lg-4, and 4 tiles across when I use col-lg-3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your CSS classes that define the layout for each tile. Then use a plugin like Isotope (to save you the time of writing all the tile rearrangement logic) - and use JS to instantiate each tile and append it to the Isotope grid. Isotope will handle the the dynamic arranging for you - just make sure to call the update layout method on Isotope each time you add a new tile dynamically.

Edit: Here is a working site that I build that uses this type of implementation. Our MVC allows us to dynamically change the questions in the FAQ grid and the layout is handled by Isotope (scroll down to FAQs). You are welcome to view source and borrow from the implementation as needed.

[Example Here](http://www.rooflesssolar.com/)